# How to reset MFA for ADB2C user through MS Graph API C#

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to reset user MFA through graph API using C# code. There is no direct Graph API available to do this, so I was trying Delete API (from V1.0) to delete the user MFA authentication methods from following url,

I am using following code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/microsoftauthenticatorauthenticationmethod-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp):

> ```
> GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
>
> await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].Authentication.MicrosoftAuthenticatorMethods["{microsoftAuthenticatorAuthenticationMethod-id}"]
>   .Request()
>   .DeleteAsync();
> ```

However I found that to create `authProvider` object we need `Microsoft.Graph.Auth` nuget pkg which is under pre-release and `Authentication.MicrosoftAuthenticatorMethods` available only in `Microsoft.Graph.Beta` nuget pkg.

When the Delete graph API is part of V1.0 how it is trying to use beta functionalities ? Can someone help me here. I want to do all these functionality only using MS Graph API V1.0 C#.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to access MS Graph depending on your application design and language requirements. To access the v1.0 endpoints in C#, you can use the [Microsoft Graph .NET sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-net-sdk). [Microsoft.Graph](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) contains the models and request builders for accessing the v1.0 endpoint with the fluent API. [Microsoft.Graph.Auth](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth) provides an authentication scenario-based wrapper of the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for use with the Microsoft Graph SDK.

As you have pointed out, the Auth sdk is available in prerelease via Nuget - adding the `-IncludePrerelease` flag should allow installation The code snippet you've posted above is available in the latest version of the Graph sdk and not in beta.

Let me know if this helps and if you have further questions

Comment: Hi Diana, thanks for your update. I used latest version of Graph sdk and the code which is mentioned above is working as expected. Only limitation I saw in V1.0 is that, I am not able to delete Email/Phone Number etc methods. Its only available in Beta version as of now as per MS document